# ASP.NET MVC 5 Synchronized HttpContext and Parallel.For(each) can it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, parallel-processing

**Basic problem**

When using Tasks/Threads under ASP.NET MVC 5 the HttpContext.Current and/or its contained instances become null. This leaves e.g. Session management useless under Parallel Tasks. And we store our User instance on the Session.

After lots of reading I found a solution that works with Tasks that are created in a plain loop and RunSynchronously. But for unknown reasons Parallel.For gets stuck in what looks a deadlock.

**Current solution**

My current solution is based on SynchronizationContext.Current being set for the Request Thread and NOT set for its "child" Tasks/Threads. On the Request thread I put the current SynchronizationContext into CallContext.LogicalSetData, Start all Tasks:

```
        CallContext.LogicalSetData("HttpRequestSyncContext", SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

...

```
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int lc = 0; lc < 1000; lc++)
        {
            tasks.Add(new Task(() =>
            {
                /// Call ServiceLayer/DAL which needs Session["MyUser"]...
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
        }

        tasks.ForEach(t => t.RunSynchronously());

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The magic comes with using the Send method on the stored SynchronizationContext: It runs the code/action in the original Request thread. Just like UI Threads doing it in WinForms:

```
        User myUser = null;
        SynchronizationContext requestSyncContext = (SynchronizationContext)CallContext.LogicalGetData("requestSyncContext");
        if (requestSyncContext != null)
        {
            requestSyncContext.Send( (state) =>
              {
                  myUser = (User)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyUser"];
              }, null);
        }
```

**Final problem**

I've tested above solution and it works for both synchroon and async (await) Tasks. But not for Parallel.For...:

```
        Parallel.For(0, 1000, (idx) =>
        {
           /// Call ServiceLayer/DAL which needs Session["MyUser"]...
        });
```

In the debugger all tasks/threads get stuck in the .Send method.

**Questions**

What is the difference between above Tasks solution and Parallel.For? Does the Parallel.For blocks the Request thread?

Help is welcome!

Thanks

**Edit 1**

Stumbled upon what looks like a solution:

```
        ParallelOptions pOptions = new ParallelOptions
        {
            TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        };

        Parallel.For(0, 1000, pOptions, (idx) =>
        {
        ...
```

The SynchronizationContext and CallContext are not needed anymore.

Together with our IoC Container Unity its Register:

```
       container.RegisterType<HttpContextBase>(
            new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(x => { return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current); })
        );
```

and its Resolve:

```
     HttpContextBase httpCtx = ServiceLayer.Container.Resolve<HttpContextBase>();
        return (User)httpCtx.Session["MyUser"];
```

Tested it under Load with multiple Browsers with a MVC Controller request that inserts 1000 Customers. Al inserts went ok.

Can anybody tell me if this is the prefered way to go?
I know that (Long running) tasks under ASP.NET (MVC) is not really a good thing but I wanted to know if its possible and maybe use it to speed up a few actions.

Thanks for feedback!

**Edit 2**

Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example(s):

Example Data access layer example:

```
public void NeedsPresentationLayerUser()
{
    // Some work e.g. DB calls

    // Need User from Presentation layer
    HttpContextBase httpCtx = ServiceLayer.Container.Resolve<HttpContextBase>();
    string userName = (string)httpCtx.Session["MyUser"];

    if ( !userName.Equals("Me") )
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Assert: UserName test failed!");
    }
}
```

Example Parallel.For test that fails.

```
public ActionResult MCVParallelTestFail()
{
    Session["MyUser"] = "Me";

    Parallel.For(0, 1000, (idx) =>
    {
        // Call down into Data Access layer...
        ServiceLayer.Db.SystemFactory.NeedsPresentationLayerUser();
    });

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Example Parallel.For test that works, but seems to be slow(er):

```
public ActionResult MCVParallelTestWorks()
{
    Session["MyUser"] = "Me";

    ParallelOptions pOptions = new ParallelOptions
    {
        TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    };

    Parallel.For(0, 1000, pOptions, (idx) =>
    {
        // Call down into Data Access layer...
        ServiceLayer.Db.SystemFactory.NeedsPresentationLayerUser();
    });

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Plain for loop that starts Tasks: Fails

```
public ActionResult MCVTasksTestFail()
{
    Session["MyUser"] = "Me";

    for(int lc = 0; lc < 1000;  lc++ )
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Call down into Data Access layer...
            ServiceLayer.Db.SystemFactory.NeedsPresentationLayerUser();
        });
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Same plain loop but now starting Tasks with .RunSynchronously():

```
public ActionResult MCVTasksTestWorks()
    {
        Session["MyUser"] = "Me";

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for(int lc = 0; lc < 1000;  lc++ )
        {
            tasks.Add(new Task(() =>
            {

                // Call down into Data Access layer...
                ServiceLayer.Db.SystemFactory.NeedsPresentationLayerUser();

            }));
        }

        tasks.ForEach(t => t.RunSynchronously());
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

As Henk Holterman pointed out there are other ways to get the User instance without having to provide a context variable in the whole flow down. We are now looking at this using CallContext.LogicalSetData / CallContext.LogicalGetData. 
First test showed that Parallel Tasks under ASP.NET MVC 5 are 3 times faster than Sequential. Inserting 1000 x one Customer.

Reading on internet showed that CallContext.Logical... are only safe in .NET 4.5+ and are not very well documented (At least not in MSDN)

**New Question:** 
Is specifically adding User instance into Logical CallContext flow threadsafe? So each request thread has to use LogicalSetData ands its child tasks/threads use LogicalGetData.

Again thanks for feedback!

Cheers

Comment: If User is the only piece of data you need from the context then there are easier methods to pass it along...

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Parallel.For blocks the Request thread?

When you call it from that thread, then: Yes.

Comment: But with the task solution it use a waitall and then the send does not block! So the wait in task seems to behave different than in parallel.for...?

Comment: Even stranger because you execute them with RunSynchronously. Without the surrounding code I can't figure this out any further. Consider creating a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

I think AsyncLocal will be a better option, it will copy the value to all child threads/tasks, but when you change it in any child thread, the value will NOT be visible by other threads, unless the value you saved is a object and you only change the value of that object, then it will be visible to other threads.